# Breaking the barriers at $q=5$ and $q=13$ for $q^k n^2$ an odd perfect number with special prime $q$

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of divisors of the positive integer $x$.  If $\sigma(N)=2N$ and $N$ is odd, then $N$ is called an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers). The question of existence of odd perfect numbers is the longest unsolved problem of mathematics.

Euler proved that an odd perfect number, if one exists, must have the form $N = q^k n^2$ where $q$ is the special prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Broughan, Delbourgo, and Zhou prove in [IMPROVING THE CHEN AND CHEN RESULT FOR ODD PERFECT NUMBERS](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf) (Lemma 8, page 7) that if $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is a square, then the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture that $k=1$ holds.

So now suppose that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is a square.  This implies that $k=1$, and also that $\sigma(n^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, since $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is odd and $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

The congruence $\sigma(n^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ then implies that $q \equiv k \pmod 8$.  (See this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310919) for the details.)  Substituting $k=1$, we obtain
$$q \equiv 1 \pmod 8.$$

This implies that the lowest possible value for the special prime $q$ is $17$.  (That is, this argument breaks the barriers at $q=5$ and $q=13$, under the assumption that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is a square.)  Note that, if $q=17$, then $(q+1)/2 = 3^2 \mid n^2$.

**Here is my question:**

> Can we push the lowest possible value from $q \geq 17$, to say, $q \geq 41$ or even $q \geq 97$, using the ideas in this post, and possibly more?

**Reference:**
[The Abundancy index of divisors of odd perfect numbers – Part III](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-3-053-059.pdf)

Comment: Isn't that more suitable for MO?

Comment: @enedil, I agree.  I just wanted to see what the folks here have to say regarding this inquiry before I cross-post it over at MO (after some time, of course).

Comment: @enedil, I have just posted an answer below a few minutes ago.  Note the simplicity in the argument.  It is for exactly this same reason that I refrain from asking my questions in MO, because they tend to be not so well-received there (as opposed to here at MSE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(q+1)/2$ is an odd square, then $(q+1)/2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, so that $q \equiv 1 \pmod {16}$. This rules out $41$, $73$, and $89$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, @PascalOchem! =)

Answer (score 0):

Let $N=q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.

Note that if
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}$$
is a square, then $k=1$ and $\sigma(q^k)/2 = (q+1)/2$ is also a square.

The possible values for the special prime satisfying $q < 100$ and $q \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ are $17$, $41$, $73$, $89$, and $97$.

For each of these values:
$$\frac{q_1 + 1}{2} = \frac{17 + 1}{2} = 9 = 3^2$$
$$\frac{q_2 + 1}{2} = \frac{41 + 1}{2} = 21 \text{ which is not a square.}$$
$$\frac{q_3 + 1}{2} = \frac{73 + 1}{2} = 37 \text{ which is not a square.}$$
$$\frac{q_4 + 1}{2} = \frac{89 + 1}{2} = 45 \text{ which is not a square.}$$
$$\frac{q_5 + 1}{2} = \frac{97 + 1}{2} = 49 = 7^2$$

Thus, if $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is a square and we could rule out $q=17$, it would follow that $q \geq 97$.

Comment: Blimey!  I missed the possibility that $q=89$.  Editing my answer now to reflect this update.